# Am I supposed to delete a downvoted question that has upvoted answers?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I usually delete downvoted questions with negative scores as I take it that the community dislikes that question. However, I am currently in the awkward position that some of the answers have received upvotes and I'm unsure what to do now.

What should I do?

Question Under Consideration:

[What are the most common additional fees (i.e. besides rent) landlords or property owners attempt to charge tenants?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/61468/what-are-the-most-common-additional-fees-i-e-besides-rent-landlords-or-proper)

Comment: That question is poor because it's a list style question, but you could definitely improve it.  "What" to look out for is hard to quantify - lots of things are possible, and varies widely by region.  But "How" to look out, as well as how to find out what to look for, might be answerable.

Comment: Hmmm, smart. I'll think about it

Answer (score 6):

Because your question has an answer with a positive score, I don't think you'll be able to delete the question.  (Based on [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317140/2600278).)

Here are your options:

- Do nothing.  You can just leave the question as it is, enjoy the answers that you've already gotten, and move on with your life.  The only downside is that the question may attract another downvote or two, but this isn't a big deal, in my opinion.  (It could also attract an upvote.)  The question will soon fall off the front page and won't get any more attention.
- Edit the question.  If you like, you could try to edit the question to make it less broad.  I'm not sure how you would do that; perhaps adding the name of the university you attend would be enough to scope it for a good answer, but there is no guarantee that this would get the question reopened.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be deleting/closing questions just because of a low score (unpopularity). You should only close/delete them for the various close reasons or if they are otherwise unwelcome to the site because of a violation of terms.

Comment: I agree that questions should only be closed when they meet a close reason, but in this case, the user is asking whether or not he should delete *his own question*.  If a user gets his question closed and has a bunch of downvotes, he may come to the conclusion that it would be best to delete his own question.  In this case, however, because of the answers posted, it is not an option for him.